# Is rigging a hip too complicated?

Tags: rigging, topology

I been searching for a way to properly rig a hip with a leg and with that journey i went to try to find tutorials for topology and rigging but sadly they didnt help.

My problem is that i want to have a rig that can lift their leg completely up, i found out its called the fetal position as a example, but every tutorial i found could only lift almost halfway before the mesh starts to improperly deform around the hip.
Is there a way to do this?

I been thinking of trying out bendy bones or disconnecting the leg and useing a sphere inside to give appearance of it being connected.

---

I wish i could phrase outthis question better but im not a verbal person im more visual. So if anyone wants to rearrange this question, please feel free.

Comment: Put stretchable bones where the muscles are and make these deform the mesh. You need a rotation of the leg to results in some linear stretching in other parts of the model. The regular bones then do not effect the mesh in such setup. Combine this with corrective shape keys to get the best results. Setting up these corrective shapes for every possible leg movement without those muscle bones is too much work. You also have the added option to drive the shapes from those muscle bones. You can even add [jiggle](https://github.com/cheece/JiggleArmature) to them.

Comment: @JaroslavJerrynoNovotny i never heard of strechable bones before but how do i put them where the muscles are?